# pandas read_sql return query string with arguments passed

Tags: python, sql, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
q = """
     select *
     from tbl 
     where metric = %(my_metric)s
     ;
     """
params = {'my_metric':'sales'}
pd.read_sql(q, mysql_conn, params=params)
```

Im using pandas read_sql function to safely pass arguments to my query string. I would like to return the final query string with the arguments replaced as well as the results. So for example, return the string:

```
select *
from tbl 
where metric = 'sales'
;
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, in that case try this:

```
import pandas as pd    
q = """
 select *
 from tbl 
 where metric = %s
 ;
 """
params = {'my_metric': 'sales'}
df = pd.read_sql(q, mysql_conn, params=[params['my_metric']])
query_string = q % params['my_metric']
```

Comment: how does this return the query string? (It also throws an error)

Comment: wait, are you just trying to format the query string, or do you want to input the resulting data from the query into a pandas DataFrame (which is what [read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) is for)?

Comment: I want both. I want to pass parameters to read_sql, but also get the query string back. With the arguments substituted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using psycopg2, then you could try using your `mysql_conn` instance to create a cursor, then [`mogrify`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html) `q`.

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
q = """
     select *
     from tbl 
     where metric = %(my_metric)s
     ;
     """
params = {'my_metric':'sales'}

cur = mysql_conn.cursor()

print cur.mogrify(q, params)
pd.read_sql(q, mysql_conn, params=params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think read_sql has that option but you can reconstitute what the query would look like with regular expressions.

```
import re
actual_q = re.sub('%\(.*\)s',params[re.findall('%\(.*\)s',q)[0].strip('%(').strip(')s')],q)
print(actual_q)

 select *
 from tbl 
 where metric = sales
 ;
```

This only works with one parameter per query. If you have more you could create a list of params found using re.findall as above and iterate over them to replace

```
q_params = re.findall('%\(.*\)s',q)
for param in q_params:
    actual_param = param.strip('%(').strip(')s')
    actual_q = re.sub('%\({}\)s'.format(actual_param), params[actual_param],q)
print(actual_q)

 select *
 from tbl 
 where metric = sales
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend and fix some issues in @tvashtar 's answer

```
actual_q = query_string
for param in q_params:
    actual_param = param.strip('%(').strip(')s')
    # 'param1'
    form_param = '%\({}\)s'.format(actual_param)
    # '%s\\(param1\\)s'
    value = str(params[actual_param]) if params[actual_param] else "\'\'"
    # '' if no value else the str of param1
    actual_q = re.sub(form_param, value, actual_q)
    print(actual_q)
```

After processing through the list of params, `actual_q` will have the value replaced query string